# Why the classifier gives me the input without any changes

Tags: java, nlp, weka, prediction, arff

I'm trying to build a classifier that segment Arabic sentences (transliterated in Buckwalter). I have attributes that read from files and I'm applying +/- 10 context window (i.e. for each word, I check 10 words before and 10 words after). The classification classes are:

B-S for the first word of the sentence, 
E-S for the last word of the sentence, 
I-S represents words in the middle,
and S for sentences that contain only one word.

```
FastVector fClasse = new FastVector();
fClasse.addElement( "I-S" );
fClasse.addElement( "B-S" );
fClasse.addElement( "E-S" );
fClasse.addElement( "S" );

if (str.length == 1) {
    element.setValue( attClasse , "S" );
} else {
    if (i == 0) {
        element.setValue( attClasse , "B-S" );
    } else {
        if (i == str.length - 1) {
            element.setValue( attClasse , "E-S" );
        } else {
            element.setValue( attClasse , "I-S" );
        }
    }
}
```

First, I used 10 attributes that check the previous classes for each word. So the results were almost 100%, especially for B-S and S classes. But even when I test the model with a non-segmented file. The model result is also the same. Literally, the model gives me the input paragraph without any changes. 
When I removed those attributes (that check the previous 10 classes), the evaluation results hugely decreased (B-S 33%).

Below is my code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-NiA_C-2YRkG19J-mZYg4BEdNnnVWbyG

it gives me an arff file that I use with weka GUI to generate a model. I'm using PART classifier.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use `else { if (...) { ... } }` over just `else if (...) { ... }`?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply...  no specific reason but it does not change the fact that the model always gives the same input as the output without any modification or the low evaluation percentage